# Python realtime camera(video) image process

Tags: opencv, camera, frame

When realtime camera detects some text, it would be processed through function(img_process in my code)

but it takes so long time(long lag), camera seems to be stopped.

I'd like to make camera pretend working continuously (keep taking and showing image)

code is as below

```
from PIL import Image     #pip install pillow
from pytesseract import * #pip install pytesseract
import pytesseract
import configparser
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from imutils.video import VideoStream
from imutils.video import FPS
import argparse
import imutils
import time
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + os.sep + 'envs' + os.sep + 'property.ini')

if __name__ == "__main__":
data = pd.read_csv('./test6.txt', sep='\t', engine='python')


print("Part N/O Scan...")

vs = VideoStream(src=1).start()
time.sleep(2.0)
fps = FPS().start()

while True:

    frame = vs.read()
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=500)

    (h, w) = frame.shape[:2]
    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(cv2.resize(frame, (300, 300)),
        0.007843, (300, 300), 127.5)

    #problem(delay) happen in this line
    img_process(frame)

    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF


    if key == ord("q"):
        break

    fps.update()


fps.stop()
print("[INFO] elapsed time: {:.2f}".format(fps.elapsed()))
print("[INFO] approx. FPS: {:.2f}".format(fps.fps()))

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
vs.stop()
```

Answer (score 0):

In that case, what I usually do is skip a few frames from the input. Add something like this in the while loop

```
while True:
    for i in range(5): # you can adjust this number
        frame = vs.read()
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=500)
```

This works pretty well if you want the video output in realtime.

Comment: Thanks for your support but it doesnt work well. Because my functuon is too heavy.is there anyother option like multiprocess?